The Gaussian distribution of least area that contains an arbitrary number of distinct specified points in {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:y>0$}
Definitions:

$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{3}(x_i,y_i)$ is a collection of $3$ distinct points in {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:y>0$}
$C\subset${$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:y>0$} is a bell curve symmetric about $x=x_0$ such that $y(x_0)=H$ and the area of the region bound by $C$ and the $x$-axis is $A$, given by $$y=H\exp\left(\frac{-H^2}{A^2}\pi(x-x_0)^2\right)$$
$B$ is the region bound by $C$ and the $x$-axis

Constraint:
$X\subset B$ $ \cup $ $C$
Wish to minimize:
Area of $B$

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be the leftmost point of $X$.
Let $(x_2,y_2)$ be the rightmost point of $X$.
I will refer to these two points as the extremal points.
I will refer to any other point as a non-extremal point.

Algorithm 1: (apply if and only if $y_1=y_2$)
Step 1
The bell curve given by $$y=H\exp\left(\frac{-H^2}{A^2}\pi(x-x_0)^2\right)$$ solves the constrained optimization problem for the two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ while ignoring $(x_3,y_3)$, where:

$H=y_1\sqrt{e}$
$$A=H\sqrt{\frac{\pi (x_1-x_2)^2}{2}}$$
$x_0=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$

If the non-extremal point $(x_3,y_3)$ is on this curve or inside the region bound by this curve and the $x$-axis then we are done. Otherwise, continue to step 2.
Step 2
After applying step 1, we now have $$y=H\exp\left((\frac{2x-x_1-x_2}{x_2-x_1})^2\ln(\frac{y_1}{H})\right)$$
To obtain the solution to the constrained optimization problem involving all three points, all we have to do is replace $H$ with $$\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(y_{3}\right)-\left(\frac{x_{3}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{2}\ln\left(y_{1}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{x_{3}-x_{0}}{x_{2}-x_{0}}\right)^{2}}\right)$$
This can be verified in this desmos simulation.

Algorithm 2: (apply if and only if $y_1\neq y_2$)
Step 1
The bell curve given by $$y=H(x_0)\exp\left(\frac{-H(x_0)^2}{A(x_0)^2}\pi(x-x_0)^2\right)$$ solves the constrained optimization problem for the two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ while ignoring $(x_3,y_3)$, where:

$$H(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(y_1^{(x_2-x)^2})-\ln(y_2^{(x_1-x)^2})}{(2x-x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)}\right)$$
$$A(x)=H(x)\sqrt{\frac{\pi (x_1-x)^2}{\ln(H(x))-\ln(y_1)}}$$
$\alpha(x)=A'(x)$
$x_0=\alpha^{-1}(0)$

If the non-extremal point $(x_3,y_3)$ is on this curve or inside the region bound by this curve and the $x$-axis then we are done. Otherwise, continue to step 2.
Step 2
To obtain the solution to the constrained optimization problem involving all three points, all we have to do is obtain the solution $(a,b,c)$ to the system of equations:
$$y_i=a\exp\left(b(x_i-c)^2\right)$$ for $i=1,2,3$

Question:
If $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(x_i,y_i)$ is a collection of $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}>3$ distinct points in {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:y>0$} then are algorithms 1 and 2 all that we would need in order to be able to solve the constrained optimization problem involving all $n$ points?
I think this is the case, and the following is my reasoning:
Suppose we have $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(x_i,y_i)$.
Then suppose we run algorithm 1 or 2 (depending on the values of $y_1$ and $y_2$).
If step 1 is complete then either we have already arrived at our solution or we have not. If step 1 is complete but we do not yet have our solution, we choose one of the $n-2$ non-extremal points to denote as $(x_3,y_3)$ and then we complete step 2.
We then repeat step 2 but now choosing a different one of the $n-2$ non-extremal points to denote as $(x_3,y_3)$.
We then repeat this process until we have chosen every one of the $n-2$ non-extremal points to denote as $(x_3,y_3)$.
Only one of these $n-2$ bell curves will actually successfully yield a Gaussian distribution that contains all of the $n-2$ non-extremal points. The one particular bell curve among these $n-2$ bell curves which does so is the solution to the constrained optimization problem.
